# CYGWIN( UNIX):How can I use variables count how many times grep finds a "yes" or "no" in the files in my directory?

Tags: unix, if-statement, for-loop, grep, cygwin

IN CYGWIN( UNIX) I am searching for the words "yes" "no" in files my directory. each file will only say "yes" or "no". How can i use variables YES=0 and NO=0 to count how many times grep finds a "yes" or "no" in the files in my directory?

Comment: Do you need to use the variables or is `grep -c` what you want?

Comment: need to use variables

Comment: how about `grep -l "YES" * | wc -l` to get 1 hit for one file?

Comment: that's not what i am asking. i have to use variables

Answer (score 0):

To count how many time yes are found:

```
  grep -rH yes . |wc -l
```